# Link disappears in IE6, reappears when links are added before it

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have the following HTML tags, which puts a jQuery icon in the link:

```
<a href="#"><span class="jquery-icon-stuff"></span>Link Text</a>
```

IE6 refuses to render said tags (presumably out of respect).

However, when I add the following tags:

```
<a href="#">Link Before</a>
<a href="#"><span class="jquery-icon-stuff"></span>Link Text</a>
```

Then the original link is happily rendered, along with the "before" and "after" links.

This seemed like a case of the IE6 [Peekaboo Bug](http://web.archive.org/web/20110717045153/http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html), but this modified version with some peekaboo bug fixin' candidates applied

```
<a href="#" style="position:relative; min-width:0; zoom: 1;"><span class="jquery-icon-stuff"></span>Link Text</a>
```

Also did not work.

Am I looking at an instance of the Peekaboo bug here? If so, why aren't my fixes working, and how can I get IE6 to reveal my work again? If it's not Peekaboo, then what is it?

**EDIT**: it doesn't need the "after" link to work - the before link only is sufficient. Also href attributes made no difference.

**EDIT THE SECOND: the problem seems to have to do with the jQuery icon span. In order to get it to display right next to the link text, I styled it with `display: inline-block;`. Removing the span (and indeed removing the inline-block rule) brought the link back, however the problem of the jQuery UI icon not being lined up with the text remains.**

Comment: Sad to know that positioniseverything.net is offline and only available via wayback machine! I've learnt so much from that site!

Comment: You may in fact be dealing with Peekaboo. Are those anchors floated? Or, is there any floated content next to the anchors? Try setting hasLayout (e.g., with `zoom:1` as you did) to the container, or the floated element itself.

Comment: I believe `zoom` is only supported for block elements.  Instead of applying the fix to the `a`, try applying it to the nearest enclosing block element.

Comment: @recursive - thank you very much for your time and attention. I tried the solution you describe and it did not work - the problem seems to lie in the fact that in order to get the jquery ui icon to display next to the text, I needed to set it to display-inline. However, display-inline is what causes IE6 to make it go away.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `href` attribute to `a` tag. Like `<a href="#"><span...`

Comment: Absolutely correct! Never use the anchor tag without it's href-attribute and a valid value.